# Python - How to stop child process when the parent script is stoped

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I exit child process when parent process is stoped?

Following is my code.

I want to stop all execution when there is KeyboardInterrupt.

```
import os, sys
scripts = ["script_1.py","script_2.py"]
try:
    for script in scripts:
        command = 'python ' + script
        os.system(command)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os._exit(1)
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

Comment: What's you *Operating System*? Not sure about `system`, you should check https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html.

Comment: My Operating System is Ubuntu 14

Comment: I tried using `subprocess.Popen`, and when pressing *Ctrl + C*, the process and it's active child died.

Comment: Yes I have adopted the subprocess.Popen() solution. Thank you so much .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to execute Python scripts within another Python script, let's do this in a Pythonic way and get rid of `os.system` for [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

```
import os
import importlib

scripts = ['script_1.py', 'script_2.py']

for filename in scripts:
    modulename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    importlib.import_module(modulename)
```

---

If your scripts are like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     # code here
     print('hello')
```

It will not works, because the `if __name__ == '__main__':` is here to ensure the part under `if` will be executed only if the file is executed as a script (and not as a module).

So, in this case the better thing to do is something like:

`script_1.py`:

```
def main():
    # code here
    print('hello')
```

And in the main script:

```
import os
import importlib

scripts = ['script_1.py', 'script_2.py']

for filename in scripts:
    modulename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    module = importlib.import_module(modulename)
    module.main()
```